# VB.NET Creation of Perfomance Counter Data on a Remote Server

Tags: vb.net, perfmon

I'm looking for a way to create a Binary Circular log file with a specific set of counters on a remote system.

I know this can be done using logman and psexec but I was hoping to find a cleaner example using VB.NET rather then breaking out and running an external program.

Here is the command line I would like to replace:

```
psexec \\%1 logman create counter BlackBox -f bincirc -max 500 -si 00:00:15 -b 01/01/2011 00:00:00 --v -o "C:\PerfLogs\BlackBox" -c "\Cache\*" "\LogicalDisk(*)\*" "\Memory\*" "\Network Interface(*)\*" "\Paging File(*)\*" "\PhysicalDisk(*)\*" "\Process(*)\*" "\Processor(*)\*" "\Redirector\*" "\Server Work Queues(*)\*" "\Server\*" "\System\*" "\Objects\*"
```

Thanks in advance for your help.